# How can I generate several Perl filehandles programmatically?

Tags: perl, filehandle

Is there any way in Perl to generate file handles programmatically?

I want to open ten files simultaneously and write to them  by using  file handle which consists of (CONST NAME + NUMBER). For example:

```
 print const_name4  "data.."; #Then print the datat to file #4
```

Comment: isn't it possible to store the file handles in an array?

Comment: There's an entire chapter in _Intermediate Perl_ about doing this. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can stick filehandles straight into an uninitialised array slot.

```
my @handles;
for my $number (0 .. 9) {
    open $handles[$number], '>', "data$number";
}
```

Don't forget that the syntax for printing to a handle in an array is slightly different:

```
print $handles[3] $data;    # syntax error
print {$handles[3]} $data;  # you need braces like this
```

Answer (score 5):

With a bit of [`IO::File`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO/lib/IO/File.pm) and [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) you can also do this:

```
use IO::File;

my @files = map { IO::File->new( "file$_", 'w' ) } 0..9;

$files[2]->print( "writing to third file (file2)\n" );
```

Answer (score 3):

These days you can assign file handles to scalars (rather than using expressions (as your example does)), so you can just create an array and fill it with those.

```
my @list_of_file_handles;
foreach my $filename (1..10) {
    open my $fh, '>', '/path/to/' . $filename;
    push $list_of_file_handles, $fh;
}
```

You can, of course, use [variable variables](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) instead, but they are a nasty approach and I've never seen a time when using an array or hash wasn't a better bet.

Comment: But if i want to write to the fifth file for example how i do it 
also you means push @list_of_file_handles, $fh; ?
thanks

Comment: print {$list_of_file_handles[4]} $data;